# How do I set network speed and duplex during boot?

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, startup, dhcp

My problem is that I have ADSL box doing autonegotiation, defaulting to 100Mb. However, my network cable does not seem to operate at that rate. The speed is set to 100Mbps but DHCP fails. I need to be able to set the speed to 10Mbps and full duplex before the computer starts connecting to the router.

I have tried setting in `/etc/network/interfaces` the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
```

With this the network connection is not available at all. If I drop out the `iface` and pre-up lines and use an old hub that operates only with 10Mbps the connection is fine.

How to do the setup correctly? I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove all but the loopback entries from /etc/network/interfaces if Network Manager is installed. I would then place the ethtool declaration in /etc/rc.local:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above exit 0, add:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot.